The use of that
Is the sentence

Scientists believed she was about 5 years old, since that’s the youngest that albatrosses can lay eggs

grammatically correct?
I don’t understand why the that appears before albatrosses.

"That [age] is the youngest (the earliest age) at which albatrosses can lay eggs."

OP enquired about the second "that" in the sentence:

Scientists believed she was about 5 years old, since that’s the youngest that albatrosses can lay eggs.

Let’s consider both uses of "that":
I. Function of first "that":.

Demonstrative Pronoun:  ("that is") The function of the first "that" in  "that's the youngest," "that" is a demonstrative pronoun referring back to the previously mentioned idea ("she was about 5 years old"). The phrase "that is" effectively means "this fact or information is."


that, pronoun.
referring to a specific thing previously mentioned, known, or understood.
"that's a good idea"

II. Function of the second "that":

Relative Pronoun ("that albatrosses") The second "that" in  "that albatrosses can lay eggs" is a relative pronoun.
It introduces a restrictive relative clause modifying the word  "youngest" and provides essential information about the youngest age being referred to.


Thank you for help.

If any of these answers have helped you, you can upvote and choose a "best" answer by accepting one, click on the tick to show which answer solved your problem.

It is correct.  "That" has many uses, here it is a conjunction.  It introduces a clause "albatrosses can lay eggs". The clause completes the phrase headed by the adjective "youngest".  It tells you about the adjective "youngest".
This is standard. Compare "I'm sure that you are right."  The clause "that you are right" completes the phrase headed by the adjective "sure".
The quote is wrong only because of the lack of a capital letter.

Thank you for help.
